# Newline literal read from file is being escaped automatically

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

I am in the process of building an assembler on top of a custom python VM.

I am using regex to parse an assembly flat file where I need to be able to represent a newline literal.

In the flat file, the line will look as follows:

`line    .BYT    '\n'`

And the regex:

`((?P<label>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+)?((?P<type>\.[a-zA-Z]+)\s+)(?P<value>(-?[0-9]+)|'(.{1,2})')`

The regex works fine - except that when it hits that newline character it returns `\\n` instead of `\n`.

I've attempted to use replacement to clean the value:

```
ipdb> ch
'\\n'
ipdb> ch.replace(r'\\', r'\')
*** SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<stdin>, line 1)
ipdb> ch.replace('\\\\', '\\')
'\\n'
```

How can I get just the raw newline character represented in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a line of text contains a `\` character followed by an `n`, then it'll look like `\\n` when `repr`'d to distinguish it from `\n`.  For example:

```
>>> a = "\\n"
>>> len(a)
2
>>> print a
\n
>>> a
'\\n'
>>> a[0]
'\\'
>>> len(a[0])
1
```

If you want to replace `\` + `n` with the newline character `chr(10)`, then you can do that easily enough:

```
>>> a = "\\n"
>>> a
'\\n'
>>> b = a.replace("\\n", "\n")
>>> b
'\n'
>>> len(a)
2
>>> len(b)
1
>>> ord(b)
10
```